# Ordering when using dynamic versions in gradle + beta versions

Tags: gradle, dynamic, dependencies, version

In a gradle file it's possible to specify a dependency with a dynamic version, like:

compile 'some.dependency:name:1.+'

This is documented to resolve the "newest" matching version. I have two questions:

**[1]** What does "newest" mean? Suppose the available versions are:

- 1.0
- 1.1-beta
- 1.1

Is the "newest" one 1.1-beta or 1.1? Does it depend at all on when the versions were published, or is it purely based on the version strings? If purely based on the strings, what ordering is used, because if it's just alphabetical then I think 1.1-beta would end up being "newer" than 1.1.

**[2]** As a publisher of a module, is there a sensible way of publishing a beta build such that developers who are depending on your module and using dynamic versions *wont* automatically pick it up? Is there a standard or recognized way of doing this?

Thanks!

*[I'm aware using dynamic versions is discouraged. These questions are from the point of view of someone providing a module, and wanting to ensure that developers who do use it and ignore this advice still don't end up pulling in something unexpected]*

Answer (score 0):

I' m guessing you are publishing to **maven**, and as I know, there should be an xml file named **maven-metadata.xml** which holds the information of the latest upload to the corresponding artifact. So I guess it does not depend on your naming convention but what you upload the **latest**. If you would upload 1.0.0.1 the latest then it would be downloaded not 1.1-beta or 1.1 versions.

For more info check [here](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/03/09/how-does-a-maven-repository-work/#maven-metadataxml).